# Casing of react-intl does not match the underlying filesystem

Tags: react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl, formatjs

#### Current behavior

`import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl`
throws eslint error

```
module "<path>/node_modules/react-intl/lib/react-intl"
Casing of react-intl does not match the underlying filesystem.eslint(import/no-unresolved)
```

This wasn't happening before, though i did a huge update jump from v2 to v4.

#### Your Environment

react-intl  4.1.1.
react       16.12.0
npm         6.13.4.
node        12.7.0.
babel-plugin-react-intl. 6.0.1

Comment: is this solved yet ? i had a similar error and posted question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63254383/casing-of-types-does-not-match-the-underlying-filesystem