# Casing of ./types does not match the underlying filesystem

Tags: webpack, filesystems, babeljs, eslint

So i had a bit weird warning from eslint

[image: warning on vscode hints]
[image: warning on vscode terminal]

'./types' is a flow type file.
I think eslint read checkbox as a lowercase while in reality it is Checkbox (capital C).

I try `git mv casesensitive tmp && git mv tmp CaseSensitive` as discussed here: [In a Git repository, how to properly rename a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183788/in-a-git-repository-how-to-properly-rename-a-directory) but it still doesnt work.
because in the past that folder is lowercase (checkbox) and renamed to Uppercase (Checkbox) but it was work of other developer, i don't know what happen in his machine until this warning come in my machine. Maybe (another assumption) it was happen because of bad config of webpack/babel, im not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Got the same issue, all I did was restart my editor (vscode).
Hope this works out for you too.

also, try copying the content of the file, deleting the file, creating a new one, pasting your content, and importing accordingly

This kind of error can be frustrating.

but as it goes, if something doesn't work, and you have no clue, try switching it off and on again

Comment: lol it disappeared for me after restart, ty!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my case I was importing a .js file in a .tsx extension file. so we can check the extension of the imported file.

Answer (score 0):

It comes because Some times the file name is changed in which you are pushing Let's say your earlier filename is cancelOrder and then you change the name to CancelOrder and then try to commit the code it will throw the same error so revert the changes and then try.

Answer (score 0):

The index file must be in lowercase letters